# how to block the loops when storing in a database?

Tags: python, xml, xbmc

I have got a problem with my current script where I'm working on the keyboard event for xbmc. When I'm pressing on the enter button of the keyboard, the code will keep firing by re-fetching the same values from the XML tags which it will keep doing it over and over for number of times and it will keep storing the same values in the database when there are few values from the XML tags called 'display-name'.

Here's the code:

```
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import xbmcaddon
import os
import urllib2
import StringIO
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as database
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class Channel:
     def __init__(self):
         self.__display_name = None
         self.__icon = None
         self.__programs = []


     def get_display_name(self):
         return self.__display_name


     def get_icon(self):
         return self.__icon


     def get_programs(self):
         return self.__programs



     def set_display_name(self, value):
         self.__display_name = value


     def set_icon(self, value):
         self.__icon = value


     def set_programs(self, value):
         self.__programs = value


     def del_display_name(self):
         del self.__display_name


     def del_icon(self):
         del self.__icon


     def del_programs(self):
         del self.__programs

     display_name = property(get_display_name, set_display_name, del_display_name, "display_name's docstring")
     icon = property(get_icon, set_icon, del_icon, "icon's docstring")
     programs = property(get_programs, set_programs, del_programs, "programs's docstring")




class Programme:
     def __init__(self):
         self.__start = None
         self.__stop = None
         self.__title = None
         self.__sub_title = None
         self.__desc = None
         self.__category = []
         self.__credits = []
         self.__icon = None
         self.__episode_num = None

     def get_episode_num(self):
         return self.__episode_num


     def set_episode_num(self, value):
         self.__episode_num = value


     def del_episode_num(self):
         del self.__episode_num


     def get_start(self):
         return self.__start


     def get_stop(self):
         return self.__stop


     def get_title(self):
         return self.__title


     def get_sub_title(self):
         return self.__sub_title


     def get_desc(self):
         return self.__desc


     def get_category(self):
         return self.__category


     def get_credits(self):
         return self.__credits


     def get_icon(self):
         return self.__icon


     def set_start(self, value):
         self.__start = value


     def set_stop(self, value):
         self.__stop = value


     def set_title(self, value):
         self.__title = value


     def set_sub_title(self, value):
         self.__sub_title = value


     def set_desc(self, value):
         self.__desc = value


     def set_category(self, value):
         self.__category = value


     def set_credits(self, value):
         self.__credits = value


     def set_icon(self, value):
         self.__icon = value


     def del_start(self):
         del self.__start


     def del_stop(self):
         del self.__stop


     def del_title(self):
         del self.__title


     def del_sub_title(self):
         del self.__sub_title


     def del_desc(self):
         del self.__desc


     def del_category(self):
         del self.__category


     def del_credits(self):
         del self.__credits


     def del_icon(self):
         del self.__icon

     start = property(get_start, set_start, del_start, "start's docstring")
     stop = property(get_stop, set_stop, del_stop, "stop's docstring")
     title = property(get_title, set_title, del_title, "title's docstring")
     sub_title = property(get_sub_title, set_sub_title, del_sub_title, "sub_title's docstring")
     desc = property(get_desc, set_desc, del_desc, "desc's docstring")
     category = property(get_category, set_category, del_category, "category's docstring")
     creditss = property(get_credits, set_credits, del_credits, "credits's docstring")
     icon = property(get_icon, set_icon, del_icon, "icon's docstring")
     episode_num = property(get_episode_num, set_episode_num, del_episode_num, "episode_num's docstring")



class Credits:
     def __init__(self):
         self.__type = None
         self.__role = None
         self.__name = None

     def get_type(self):
         return self.__type


     def get_role(self):
         return self.__role


     def get_name(self):
         return self.__name


     def set_type(self, value):
         self.__type = value


     def set_role(self, value):
         self.__role = value


     def set_name(self, value):
         self.__name = value


     def del_type(self):
         del self.__type


     def del_role(self):
         del self.__role


     def del_name(self):
         del self.__name

     type = property(get_type, set_type, del_type, "type's docstring")
     role = property(get_role, set_role, del_role, "role's docstring")
     name = property(get_name, set_name, del_name, "name's docstring")




class MyClass(xbmcgui.WindowXML):

     def __new__(cls):
         return super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, 'script-tvguide-mainmenu.xml', ADDON.getAddonInfo('path'))



def onInit(self):
    pass


def load_channel(self, elem):
         channel = Channel()
         for elem in elem.getchildren():
             if elem.tag == 'display-name':
                 channel.set_display_name(elem.text)
             elif elem.tag == 'icon':
                 channel.set_icon(elem.attrib['src'])
         return channel



     def load_programme(self, elem):
         programme = Programme()
         programme.set_start(elem.attrib['start'])
         programme.set_stop(elem.attrib['stop'])

         for elem in elem.getchildren():
             if elem.tag == 'title':
                 programme.set_title(elem.text)
             elif elem.tag == 'sub-title':
                 programme.set_title(elem.text)
             elif elem.tag == 'desc':
                 programme.set_desc(elem.text)
             elif elem.tag == 'category':
                 categories = programme.get_category()
                 categories.append(elem.text)
             elif elem.tag == 'episode-num':
                 programme.set_episode_num(elem.text)
             elif elem.tag == 'credits':
                 creditss = programme.get_credits()
                 creditss.append(self.load_credits(elem))
             elif elem.tag == 'icon':
                 programme.set_icon(elem.attrib['src'])
         return programme



     def load_credits(self, elem):
         creditss = Credits()
         for elem in elem.getchildren():
             if elem.tag == 'actor':
                 creditss.set_name(elem.text)
                 creditss.set_type('actor')
             elif elem.tag == 'presenter':
                 creditss.set_name(elem.text)
                 creditss.set_type('presenter')
             elif elem.tag == 'director':
                 creditss.set_name(elem.text)
                 creditss.set_type('director')
         return credits



def onAction(self, action):

if action == ACTION_ENTER:
    #OPEN THE XML SOURCE
    url = ADDON.getSetting('ontv.url')
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = response.read()
    response.close()

    profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))

   if os.path.exists(profilePath):
       profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
       con = database.connect(profilePath)
       cur = con.cursor()
       cur.execute('CREATE TABLE programs(id TEXT, channel TEXT, title TEXT, start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP, description TEXT)')
       con.commit()
       con.close
       tv_elem = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(data)).getroot()
       channels = {}

       for elem in tv_elem.getchildren():
           if elem.tag == 'channel':
              channels[elem.attrib['id']] = self.load_channel(elem)
           elif elem.tag == 'programme':
               # get channel
               channel = channels[elem.attrib['channel']]
               # load program in channel
               channel.get_programs().append(self.load_programme(elem))

               # Print the loaded data
               for channel_key in channels:
                   channel = channels[channel_key]
                   print channel.get_display_name() + ' :: ' + channel.get_icon() + ' :: Total programs = ' + str(len(channel.get_programs()))


                   display_name = channel.get_display_name()

                   profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))
                   profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
                   con = sqlite3.connect(profilePath)
                   cur = con.cursor()

                   if not display_name in cur:
                       cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(id, channel)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [display_name, 0])
                       con.commit()
                       cur.close
                       print 'Channels store into database are now successfully!'
```

Here's the xml logs: http://xbmclogs.com/show.php?id=143587

Here's the database: http://testbox.elementfx.com/source.db

And here's the xml file: http://ontv.dk/xmltv/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c

I only want to write the values in a database without keep re-fetching the same values over and over when I get the values from the XML tags.

Do you know how I can stop re-fetching the same values over and over when I store them in a database without keep running like a loop?

Comment: Why don't you try to simply track a timestamp and reject all enters for `x`-(mili)seconds since the last query started so accidental triggers won't happen?

Comment: @Allendar I don't know much simply track a timestamp. Can you post the source that would not re-fetching so many same values which will only get the value from the XML tags?

Comment: I don't really see what source you would need. You simple set a global timestamp variable and let it check on the button-press event handling. There's no need to track anything after that :)

Comment: I have a problem with the source somewhere in for elem in tv_elem.getchildren(): because it will re-fetching the same value from each XML tag which I want to fetch one value for each tag. On my code, it will re-fetching 5 same values in each tag. Can you help me how i can only fetch one value from each tag?

Comment: @Allendar do you know??????

Comment: @Allendar can you please answer it?